# Any QGIS plugin to facilitate the creation of hiking maps?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, print-composer, software-recommendations

There used to be this one https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AreaPrinter-master/

whose description reads::

> AreaPrinter simplifies the process of creating print composers for
>   navigation-quality hiking maps. It produces a print composer with km
>   grid, scale and ruler for an area that may span several pages.
>   Currently A4 paper, 1:10k,1:25k or 1:50k scales, and WGS 84 / UTM
>   projections are supported. Warning: Verify the correctness of map
>   before using it, author takes no responsibility. Using the geomag
>   library for WMM2010 magnetic declination model.

This would be perfect for what I need. Unfortunately though it only works with QGIS up to 2.18.

Is there anything similar for QGIS 3.X?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't use QGIS 2.18 for this? You're able to install multiple versions of QGIS on the same machine so you wouldn't need to uninstall your current version.

Comment: How long does it take you to set up a print layout with a map, grid and scale? Surely less time than you're spending searching for a plugin to do it for you. Once you have one layout setup you can save it as a template and re-use it to produce as many maps as you need. That said, the QuickPrint plugin sounds pretty similar to AreaPrinter. The only thing missing is the grid, but you could add that as a map canvas decoration.

Comment: The point isnt' about setting the grid and the scale, is having an atlas with multiple pages. I find it hard to do and a premade plugin would help a lot. 
Unfortunately "Quick Print" only creates a single page.
I'll try installing 2.18 and hope that my project would work there. Thanks to both.

Comment: unfortunately installing qgis2.18 on Linux looks more complicated than I expected. I can't find a binary and that would likely be dependent on older packages. Same goes for building from source, I tried to no avail for the same reason. :-(